# Performance implication of duplicate keys on React children in large lists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, virtual-dom

The [React Documentation on Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) says

> When children have keys, React
>   uses the key to match children in the original tree with children in
>   the subsequent tree.

I understand that with every list item having a unique key, the DOM doesn't have to be updated when the list items don't change.

*However*, what happens when you have a large list of 1000 elements with unique keys, but 3 elements have duplicate keys?
Are all other list items with unique keys safe from being re-rendered again? 
Or do the few items with the same key `render` the diffing algorithm useless?

Answer (score 1):

React will think the items with the same keys are the exact same item and when it tries to compute changes to the DOM, will only render 1 of the 3 items.  A quick code scan shows it will try to be optimistic and complete rendering the other items successfully.